# Use a batch file to find a value in a php.ini file

Tags: php, svn, batch-file

I currently have a batch file to do an SVN update on a branch.  I am using VisualCron to complete this task every morning so ensure I have the latest code.  However, when I switch to a new branch, I will need to update the batch file each time.

Is there a way to create a batch file to

1. Search through a file (php.ini) and find the value that is defined in this file
2. Define it as a variable in the batch file
3. Use my existing batch file code to so an SVN update on the value found in step 1

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @npocmaka I inserted "include_path=" in place of "key" and the cmd window shows "include_path=".;C:\test\test" Shouldn't I be able to enter "echo include_path=" or echo %%A=%%B or "%%%A=%%B%" and see .;C:\test\test ?  Therefore, when enter "svn /command:update /path:"include_path=" I am not getting the directory C:\test\test.  I have tried a few different things as I am learning batch files, but I appear to be struggling.  Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer.there was one forgotten `=`

Comment: How I can verify why include_path= has found? Shouldn't echo include_path= work?

Comment: Not sure what are asking about...Could send a link to an example `php.ini` and and tell me what the result should look like?

Comment: Sure, the line in the php.ini file is `include_path=".;C:\branch123"` so I want to pull branch123 from the file then `CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN
TortoiseProc.exe svn /command:update /path:" %%B AKA C:\branch123"` and when I update the php.ini file to use branch456, I do not want to update the .bat file, it should know to do an SVN update on C:\branch456.  So if I run your code `cd C:\php
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%A in ('type php.ini ^| find "include_path=" ') do (
 if "%%B" neq "" set "%%A=%%B" 
)` what should I `echo` to test I am pulling branch123? should I `echo %%B`?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `php.ini` file like this:

```
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
variable3=value3
```

use this code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (php.ini) do set "%%~a"
echo(%variable1%-%variable2%-%variable3%
```